# Navigation - Open on hover with mouse, tap with touch

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, touch, mouse

So I'm shocked this isn't a more common thing out there, I've searched high and low and only find solutions that come close.

I need a navigation menu with submenus that open via hover on desktop, and via tap on mobile/tablets/touch

There are a few requirements, for which I will use the below sample menu as a reference:

```
- Home
- About
- - Overview
- - Leadership
- - History
- Contact
```

Requirements:

- With mouse: Clicking "About" should open the about page.
- With mouse: Hovering over "About" should open the submenu.
- With mouse: Mouse leaving the navigation should close submenu (unless hovering over a sub-sub menu)
- With touch: Tapping "About" should open the submenu
- With touch: Tapping "About" should NOT open the about page (that's why there is an "overview" page).
- With touch: Tapping Outside the navigation menu should close the submenu
- With touch: Tapping "About" while open should close the submenu

The reason I say "mouse" and "touch" vs "desktop" and "mobile" is because I need to consider PC's that have touch screens (Surface, Yoga, etc). Most solutions I have seen don't take this into consideration, and cause these devices to act like touch screens even when using a mouse.

My current code is currently only opening the menu on click regardless of device:

```js
$("a.dropdown").click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("open")) {
    $(this).removeClass("open");
    $(this).next("ul").slideUp(100);
    $(this).next("ul").children("li").children("ul").slideUp(100);
    $(this).next("ul").children("li").children("a.dropdown").removeClass("open");
  } else {
    $(this).parent().siblings().children("ul").slideUp(100);
    $(this).parent().siblings().children('a.dropdown').removeClass('open');
    $(this).addClass("open");
    $(this).next("ul").slideDown(100);
  }
});
$('html').click(function() {
  $('.main-nav li ul').slideUp(100);
  $('.main-nav li a.dropdown').removeClass('open');
});
$('.main-nav li').click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="main-nav">
  <li>
    <a href="/">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown">About</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="/about">Overview</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/leadership">Leadership</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/history">History</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: And your code is ??? at least the html markup and hover behavior ?

Comment: @DaniP My current code only does it by click since I haven't found a solution at all yet, so didn't think it would be useful, but I edited my post to include it now anyway.